# Tradução marcada como duplicada

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

A seguinte frase não está traduzida para português:

> ```
> This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.
> ```

Como se pode verificar [na seguinte pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117568/assinar-nfs-e-em-c-gera-erro-elemento-reference-mal-formado/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versão traduzida vai pro ar com o próximo build